# Issue with displaying div tag using jquery colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Here is my HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title></title>
   <link href="css/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
   <script>
     function alertme(){
       alert(""+$("#text1").val()+$("#text2").val());
     }
     function enable_colorbox(){
       console.log("inside colorbox");
       jQuery("#inline").colorbox({inline:true});
     }
   </script> 
</head>
<body>
  <div id="inline" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" id="text1" />
    </br>
    <input type="text" id="text2" />
    <input type="submit" value="clickme" onclick="alertme()"/>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" onclick="enable_colorbox()" />
</body>
</html>
```

I have a div tag that I have made invisible and outside the div tag , I have a submit button which on click calls the colorbox on the div tag. Nothing happens. I am not sure what is the issue. I don't get any errors in the console.

The js and css files are in my local server. I can launch the html file and view the css and js files through the browser.

Please advice

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
jQuery("#inline").colorbox({inline:true});
```

To this:

```
$.colorbox({inline:true, href: "#inline" });
```

**Add demo:**
[jsfiddle.net/TpVn6/](http://jsfiddle.net/TpVn6/)

Comment: Using the above code, colorbox opens now but nothing is visible. I mean both the text fields and the button could not be seen.

Comment: @PSathiya Also you need to create extra div, look at my demo.

Comment: Thank you. it worked. The problem is, it seems I have to manually enable the display of the div tag.Once I did that, I could open the file. Thank you

Comment: Thank you. Worked fine after adding an extra div tag around the div(id=inline).

Comment: @PSathiya Not at all, mark answer as correct, if you think it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

What is this : `jQuery("#inline").colorbox(**{inline:true}**);` ? Shouldn't be `display:inline` ?

Comment: I changed the code to `$("#inline").colorbox({display:inline});` . Colorbox is not visible. But when I checked the page through chrome console, the div tag with id=colorbox is now available below the input "submit" . But colorbox is not visible.